# Does micronaut support loading Enum Fields as Bean Definitions?

Tags: enums, micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-openapi

In my micronaut application I have various Enum fields that contain an annotation (AnnotationA).  When this annotation is placed on a Bean class (not an enum), I can use the following statement to retrieve all of the Bean definitions containing this annotation.

`applicationContext.getBeanDefinitions(Qualifiers.byStereotype(AnnotationA.class))`

But when the same annotation is placed on an enum value I cannot use this same call to retrieve all of the enums that have this annotation.  Would anyone happen to know of a way that I can retrieve the enum values containing this annotation?

Comment: afaik enum cannot be Micronaut beans. but can you explain our use case and what are you trying to solve?

Comment: That is correct.  There would be no reason to have an enum value as a bean in the application context.  Beans could have enum value properties in them, but the enum values would not be beans as there is no reason to do that.

Comment: So my use case is that I have enums that have annotations on the elements and i would like to load all enums containing those annotations without using java reflections.